# Simultaneous Deployment In Websphere

Tags: deployment, websphere, ear, ibm-was

I have a question. I Actually have around 25 ears to deploy onto WAS. I am doing it one by one. This is costing me a lot of time.

Now i am just thinking is it a good idea to deploy few ears at one time. Meaning I want to deploy 3-4 ears parallel to the same was server (to save time). Is my thinking correct. If yes, please guide me how to proceed.

Regards

Answer (score 3):

There are some resources for speeding up application deployment, but they don't revolve around parallel deployment. For many reasons, I don't see parallel deployment being advised. Deploying two EARs at the same time would likely make both take twice as long.

You could [automate](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/txml_callappinstall.html) the deployment into a wsadmin script or look into some ways to [speed deployment](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0812_webcon/0812_webcon.html) or if the applications being deployed are large and have lots of binaries or packages that do not have JEE annotations, you can look into [annotation filtering](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/trun_app_reduce_annot.html) which can reduce deployment time.

It wasn't specified, but if you are using WebSphere Liberty, then [application deployment](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_dep.html) is inherently different, so you could specify all of the application configuration data in one place, the server.xml, and simply copy the EARs to deploy.